# Finding divisions

Tags: python, primes

I'm quite new to programming and I've heard this is a good place to get started. I'm working with python through the Project Euler Questions and I'm stuck on question 7. I have a way of completing it but it is extremely inefficient and the main question I'm asking is if there is a way to check for all factors of an integer in a way that doesn't mean typing them all in.
So far this is what I have:

```
counter=0

prime_counter=0

for x in range(1,10000):

    if x%2 and x%3 and x%4 and x%5 and x%6 and x%7 and x%8 and x%9 and x%10 and x%11 and x%12 and x%13 and x%14 and x%15 and x%16 and x%17 and x%18 and x%19 and x%20 and x%21 and x%22 and x%23 and x%24 and x%25 and x%26 and x%27 and x%28 and x%29 and x%30 and x%31 and x%32 and x%33 and x%34 and x%35 and x%36 and x%37 and x%38 and x%39 and x%40 and x%41 and x%42 and x%43 and x%44 and x%45 and x%46 and x%47 and x%48 and x%49 and x%50 !=0:
        counter+=1
        prime_counter+=x

    if counter==10001:
        break
print(counter)

print(prime_counter)
```

You can see my issue here and feel free to laugh but I'm quite new and I was wondering if I could get some help.
I completely forgot, the whole purpose of the code is to figure out the 10,001st prime number

Comment: Use another loop. Inside your first loop, `for y in range(2, 100)`, for example.

Comment: how exactly would I employment that in the code?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, that does not solve the inefficiency

Comment: Testing a number for being prime is a hard task. An inner loop is the most straight forward way. An optimization would be to test only the odd numbers (and 2 of course).

Comment: See [Generating Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) and in particular the algorithm [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to mark a number as non-prime if it has a modulus of `0` with a factor. So instead of hardcoding all the factors, you could use some function to generate all these numbers... like `range`.

The other question is "what should the range of factors for testing be, given a number?". It turns out that you need to only test for the numbers in [2, sqrt(n)]. Also, note that we only need to check if any prime number is a factor

Putting these two pieces together:

```
primes = [2]  # list of all the prime numbers
n = 3
while len(primes) < 10001:  # until we find the required number of prime numbers
    F = n**0.5
    prime = True
    for f in (p for p in primes if p<=F):
        if not n%f:  # found a factor
            prime = False
            break
    if prime:
        primes.append(n)
    n += 2  # test only the odd numbers

print(primes)
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Your generator expression does not need a comma.  You may want to calculate `n**0.5` before the for-loop to avoid recalculating it for each iteration.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: thanks for the notes. I really shouldn't code while proofreading for grammar :P

Comment: Great answer and great name! @inspectorG4dget :)

Comment: I ran that code but I'm not sure it gave the answer I was expecting, or when I try to pull a certain number for example the 100th prime it gives a different number and I'm not sure where that came from

Comment: @camg132: Check out the update. I just spotted an error

Comment: @camg132: create a list of 10001 prime numbers, and access the last element in that list :)